# Can I use jquery impromptu to display asp.net form with server controls in it?

Tags: jquery, impromptu

for example I have div like this

```
<div id="dvSignup">
// a full working form of asp.net server controls
</div>
```

I want to display this div in jquery impromptu popup.
any example plz
iframe not to use for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Impromptu works on jQuery which renders at the client browser. you should use ajax to submit the form data to the server. following is the code have a look

```
    var statesdemo = {state0: {
    title: 'Some title for heading',
    html:'some text',
    buttons: { Next: 1 },
    //focus: "input[name='fname']",
    submit:function(e,v,m,f){
    console.log(f);
    e.preventDefault();
    $.prompt.goToState('state1');
    }
    },
    state1: {
    title: 'next title',
    html:'
    <center>
        <textarea name="comments" rows="5" cols="49" style="border-color: #f4f4f4;" placeholder="Enter your requirements..."></textarea>
    </center>',
    buttons: { Back: -1, Done: 1 },
    focus: 1,
    submit:function(e,v,m,f){

    e.preventDefault();
    if(v==1) $.prompt.close();
    if(v==-1) $.prompt.goToState('state0');
    $('#mediaType_other').val(f.comments);
    }
    }
    };

    var ThankYou = {state0: {
    title: '',
    html:'Thank you your quote has been submitted',
    buttons: { Ok: 1 },
    //focus: "input[name='fname']",
    submit:function(e,v,m,f){
    console.log(f);
    if(v==1){ $.prompt.close();
    window.location="http://www.yourweb.com/quote.php";
    }
    }
    }

    };
```